# Cannot get boolean value from excel cell

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, file, apache-poi

I am getting an error when trying to access a boolean value from an Excel file.

```
final Cell enabledCell = row.getCell(6);
enabledCell.getBooleanCellValue() // this throws an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a BOOLEAN value from a STRING cell
```

In the Excel file, I have just written "TRUE" and "FALSE" as values in the 6th column, but somehow they are perceived as strings and not booleans.

Comment: Looks like excel thinks the two values are strings.

Comment: I think you need to either change the Excel file input or get the cell value as string, and then a simple string equals should do the trick

Answer (score 5):

Boolean values in localized Excel applications also are localized. For example in my German Excel boolean values are `WAHR` and `FALSCH`. If I put `TRUE` or `FALSE` into cells using my German Excel GUI, then this are **not** boolean values but text strings.

So there is always the need to check `CellType` before getting the cell value. Or to use `DataFormatter` to always get string values independent of cell type.

Both is shown in [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features->Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents).

Moreover you might get the wrong cell. In [Row.getCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-) the `int cellnum` is 0-based. Column `A` is `cellnum` 0. So `cellnum` 6 is column `G`, which is the 7th column and not the 6th. But that's secondary. Primary is the need to check `CellType` before getting the cell value or to use `DataFormatter`.